# How to split a big React application to several "mini apps" to improve performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

we are working on a big react project, which contains 3 major parts, let's say they are PA, PB and PC. Right now, we use react router to link them together. However, they are kinda independent from each other. When user click a button in PA, it will open a new page and jump to PB or PC via url, like www.xxx.com/#PB. In other words, when PA is working, we don't need any components from PB or PC, vise versa. PA, PB, PC never works on the same running environment.

Right now, in the App.js you can see something like this:
[Demo script screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWijw.png)

Since PA, PB, PC are all really big, they may contains more than 100 components separately. We found that, app gets slower and slower when the project grows.

We have done some tests found out that, if we remove the import of PB and PC when only load PA, like the following image shows, the app can start to render content within 1000ms, but with imports of PB and PC, the app starts to render in 1600ms. This is a huge difference for user experience. (PS: please don't care about network io, we did the tests on dev machine, network io is nothing)
[Demo codes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWB6V.png)

In order to provide better experience, we are thinking about split the application into "mini apps", for example, when users visit www.xxx.com/#PA, the APP.js only loads PA components. When users visit www.xxx.com/#PB, the APP.js only loads PB components.

We don't know how to do this. 
Can you guys help us?
Thank you very much.

PS: we have read articles about Lazy and Suspense, they seems like more related to network\data fetching, not exactly what we need.

Comment: BTW, we don't want to split the project into 3, it makes development more cumbersome. And, code splitting is not really useful in our case, it only helps for networking performance.